# Round function not working properly in php version 5.1.6

Tags: php

1)

```
$b = 468.7+468.7+468.7+468.7+468.7+468.7+468.7+175+175+175+175+175+175+175+175+175+175+175+175+175+175+689.8+689.8+0+0+0;

echo "<br><======>".$b;//gives 7110.5
echo "<br><======>".round($b);//gives 7111
```

2)

```
$k = 7110.5;

echo "<br><======>".$k; // gives 7110.5
echo "<br><======>".round($k);//gives 7111
```

3)

```
$c = 175+468.7+175+689.8+175+468.7+175+468.7+175+689.8+175+175+468.7+175+175+175+468.7+175+175+175+468.7+175+468.7;

echo "<br><======>".$c; // gives 7110.5
echo "<br><======>".round($c); // gives 7110
```

if you check in 3rd eg the round up value is not correct it has to be 7111.
In 1st and 3rd eg only difference is the arrangement of values.

Kindly suggest why the 3rd eg given fails

Comment: checked with 5.6 working fine, may be some issue with 5.1

Answer (score 1):

1. suggestion you should use newer version of php
2. actually it was a bug in php 5.1 which was fixed later. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34599
3. still you want the exact result in 5.1

   ```
    round($c, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
   ```

it might work for you to solve your problem,

Answer (score 0):

Don't have access to this version of PHP. And best solution for such situation is to upgrade to some newer version - PHP 7 just been released after all.

If you can not upgrade, you could try one of the workarounds here:
Casting to (float) each number in your sum
Casting to (float) result  - `(float) $c`
Casting to (string) and then to (float) result  - `(float)(string) $c`

Don't know if any of it would help, but worth a try if you only need a workaround. Unfortunately, besides guessing that this issue might be related to some underlying way PHP handles variables and numbers I can't explain why rounding in your case doesn't work.

There's a mention of similar issue on PHP Bugs Tracker here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=36008

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution for this problem can be use round and number_format in combination.

Ex: $amount = round(number_format($amount,8,".",""),2);